# using api to call users and material ui data grid to show users

Tags: reactjs, rest, material-ui, datagrid

i am working on an application that I make API calls to get some users for an id. the API gives you the users in an object of 25 length, and i  order to get the other users u have to make other API calls.

I have a parent component from which I look for users and I pass down some variables to my child component:

```
<UserSection
                    id={id}
                    code={code}
                    open={open}
                    users={users}
                    setOpen={setOpen}
                    handleClose={handleClose}
                    handleUsers={handleUsers}
                    total={total}
                    currentPageNr={currentPageNr}
                    maxPageNr={maxPageNr}
                  />
```

then in my child component I am using the material ui data grid as follows:

```
  const [rowsState, setRowsState] = React.useState({
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 25,
    rows: [],
    loading: false,
  });



const rows = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    (async () => {
      setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: true }));
      await fetchAllUsers(rowsState.page);

      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].campaign_id == props.id) {
          let row = {
            id: i + 1,
            col1: i + 1,
            col2: users[i].id,
            col3: users[i].first_name,
            col4: users[i].qualified,
            col5: users[i].email,
            col6: users[i].source,
            col7: users[i].referrer_id,
            col8: showName(users[i].referrer_id),
            // col9: props.users[i].url,
            col10: justSHowReached(users[i].id),
            col11: users.filter(
              (u) => u.referrer_id == users[i].id && u.qualified
            ).length,
            col12: changeDate(users[i].date),
            // col13: "",
          };
          rows[i] = row;
        }
      }

      const newRows = rows;

      console.log("new rows:", newRows);
      console.log("eowsState.page:", rowsState.page);
      // console.log("===**=== rowsState.pageSize:", rowsState.pageSize);

      if (!active) {
        return;
      }
      setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: false, rows: newRows }));
    })();

    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [rowsState.page, rowsState.pageSize]);
```

and this is how I try to fetch users based on page number:

```
const fetchAllUsers = async (pageNumber) => {
    console.log("----------------------------------");
    console.log("page number: ", pageNumber);
    console.log("----------------------------------");
    await fetch(
      `........./api/v1/users?page=${pageNumber}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        }),
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(async (data) => {
        // console.log("=================rows=================");
        setUsers(data.data);
        return data.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

so I set my users here which I want to use on data model.

and also

```
  const columns = [
    { field: "col1", headerName: "#", width: 50 },
    { field: "col2", headerName: "Id", width: 100, sortable: false },
    { field: "col3", headerName: "Name", width: 100 },
    { field: "col4", headerName: "Qualified", width: 100 },
    { field: "col5", headerName: "Email", width: 200 },
    { field: "col6", headerName: "Source", width: 75 },
    { field: "col7", headerName: "Referrer Id", width: 125 },
    { field: "col8", headerName: "Referrer Name", width: 125 },
    // { field: "col9", headerName: "Url", width: 300 },
    {
      field: "col10",
      headerName: "Reached",
      width: 150,
    
    },
    { field: "col11", headerName: "Qualified", width: 150 },
    { field: "col12", headerName: "Date Created", width: 150 },
    {
      field: "col13",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 150,
      sortable: false,
      filterable: false,
      hideable: false,

      renderCell: (params) => {
        const onClick = (e) => {
          e.stopPropagation(); // don't select this row after clicking

          const api = params.api;
          const thisRow = {};

          api
            .getAllColumns()
            .filter((c) => c.field !== "__check__" && !!c)
            .forEach(
              (c) => (thisRow[c.field] = params.getValue(params.id, c.field))
            );

          console.log("---->", thisRow.col2, thisRow.col4);

          setUserId(thisRow.col2);
          updateUser(thisRow.col2, thisRow.col4);
          //   return alert(JSON.stringify(thisRow, null, 4));
        };

        return (
          <>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={onClick}>
              update
            </Button>
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
```

this is how I make my model:

```
<DataGrid
  // rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  pagination
  rowCount={props.total}
  paginationMode="server"
  // pageSize={25}
  rowsPerPageOptions={[25]}
  {...rowsState}
  onPageChange={(page) => {
    // console.log("and page is ", page);
    setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, page }));
  }}
  onPageSizeChange={(pageSize) =>
    setRowsState((prev) => ({ ...prev, pageSize }))
  }
/>
```

the problem is that I load users but I wont be able to show them inside my model

here u can see:[image]

I am loading 25 users but the model doesn't show anything, however it shows me `1–25 of 5101` when i click on `>` I can load the users on my model like but now I am on `26–50 of 5101` so I am in page 2 but I am showing the data for page 1, when i click on `>` again I can see that this works but I am always behinds the correct page and sometimes Im in page 6 but I am still seeing data for page 2, and I can see that model is not being updated correctly.

on my dependency on my `useEffect` I have  `[rowsState.page, rowsState.pageSize],` while the [toturial says](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/pagination/#server-side-pagination)  I need to  have 3, and the 3rd one is the rows, if I put users there, the app will keep rendering and eventually firefox will crush. How can i make sure I am getting the correct data for every page and also how to load the data directly to the model?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, and I think your component is overall too complex. If you try and simplify things you might make it easier to see the problem.

First, I'd move the `fetchAllUsers` out to a separate method - it doesn't need to use state, it can just be a simple wrapper around an API call. Also, given that it's fetching a subset of users, it should probably not be called "fetchAllUsers". And, you're mixing `async/await` with promises - just stick with using `async/await`. Something like this might work

```js
const fetchUsersForPage = async (pageNumber) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
        // Copied from your code but looks very suspicious...
        `........./api/v1/users?page=${pageNumber}`,
        {
            method: "GET",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            }),
        });

        const { data } = await response.json();
        return data;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

I'd also suggest you encapsulate the loading of the paged data into a separate hook. [This article does a good job of explaining why you should use custom hooks for encapsulation](https://kyleshevlin.com/use-encapsulation). Your effect also has a dependency on the `props.id` which looks like it's a campaign id. Again, something like this might work - there's a few red flags in there which I've commented in the code below:

```js
const usePagedData = (campaignId, page, pageSize) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadPageData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);

            const users = await fetchUsersForPage(page);

            const userRows = users
                // This looks suspicious - you might be losing users because they
                // don't match the campaign? Shouldn't you pass the campaignId
                // as part of the fetch in that case?
                .filter(user => user.campaign_id === campaignId)
                .map((user, index) => ({
                    id: index + 1,
                    col1: index + 1,
                    col2: user.id,
                    col3: user.first_name,
                    col4: user.qualified,
                    col5: user.email,
                    col6: user.source,
                    col7: user.referrer_id,

                    // Not sure what these functions are??
                    col8: showName(user.referrer_id),
                    // col9: props.users[i].url,
                    col10: justSHowReached(user.id),

                    // This number will almost certainly be wrong since 'users' is
                    // the list of users for this page.
                    col11: users.filter(u => u.referrer_id == user.id && u.qualified).length,
                    col12: changeDate(user.date),
                    // col13: "",
                  }));
            
            setRows(userRows);      
        }

        loadPageData();
    }, [campaignId, page, pageSize]);

    return {
        rows,
        loading
    }
}
```

Now your component that contains the data grid can use your custom hook as follows:

```js
const { rows, loading } = usePagedData(props.id, page, pageSize);
```

Comment: thanks for the awesome explanation, you should know I am doing this for a company to find out what is the problem with their api, so the application might not make sense, their api gives all the users and you need to use campaignId to make sure you only get users belonging to that campaign thus the filter (one of the things i mentioned to them about the api), you can refer people to campaign and then u can see who referd who (justSHowReached), showName a function to print the name of the person who invited you to the campaign.

Comment: this works fine however, i still have the same problem as before, thw first two page are the same data, and after page 3 it changes, but somes times it doesnt change correctly

Comment: I fixed it by adding the row as dependency to my useeffect

Comment: but still sometimes doesnt work, also === doesnt work byt == works in my case!

Comment: In the code you've posted, I can't see why `row` is needed as a dependency. Sorry, I don't think I'm going to be able to help further without seeing the rest of the code. The principle holds though - try and simplify the code, that's usually the best way of isolating the problem. If `===` doesn't work but `==` does, it means that the types must be different (e.g. one string and one number).

Comment: thank you alot, you have helped so much already

Comment: the other issue is if I want to want to figure who referred who and how many referred a person has then I need to pull all the users (5103) in this case which is over 204 api calls to get all the users and then I need to go  through them to find what i need

Comment: Eeek... sounds like you need to get that company to update their API for you!